# Delete Hidden/Invisible Rows after Autofilter Excel VBA Part II

Tags: vba, excel

New poster here.

I am using the below code in order to filter by the name of the firm in my workbook. I have multiple tabs labelled 1-11 that I'd like to do so in.

```
Sub FilterByFirm()

' FilterByFirm Macro



ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$QP$8000").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
    "UBS Global Asset Management"

Dim oRow As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRows As Range
With Sheets("3")
    Set myRows = Intersect(.Range("A:A").EntireRow, .UsedRange)
    If myRows Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End With

For Each oRow In myRows.Columns(1).Cells
    If oRow.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = oRow
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, oRow)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

I have been going through and updating the Sheets("3") to the tab that I am currently working in because this seemed to be how to make things work. However, this did not work in tab 10 (called "10"). It worked in every other tab, and I am not sure why. Instead of filtering and then deleting hidden rows, the macro has been simply deleting all the rows.

How can I correct this? And I can confirm that UBS appears in tab 10, so this is not the issue.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried running through the code when you do it for 'tab 10' to see what it does, line by line? Doing it like this will show you your problem if you expect a result and don't get it. ie: "I expected row 5 to show up as 'not hidden' - so why did Excel think it was hidden and delete it?"

Comment: The first thing that pops out at me is that you are first filtering by the `ActiveSheet`, then working with a different sheet (in your case `Sheet("3")`. If `3` is not the active sheet, then it too is not the sheet that will be filtered. Did you notice this limitation, and is it done this way by design?

Comment: Do you know that you can do "For Each (Worksheet Variable) in (Workbook Name).Sheets"?

Comment: Going further with @user3561813, beware that you have likely deleted content from all of those other sheets if indeed you ran this code with a different sheet active than the one intended.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding and thank you to everyone for their comments.

I realized that the issue was that on Tab 10, the first column didn't have a filter on it, so the macro kept trying to filter the 6th FILTERED column which was the seventh overall column, which was screwing it up. I appreciate that I should've solved this on my own.

Secondly, I am greatly interested in being able to just run the macro once and have it work on all sheets, which seems to be what people are saying in the comments I could do, but I'm not sure how to implement. Could you elaborate further on how?

Comment: Essentially I'd like to just have the user enter the Raw Input once and then have it filter on all sheets, and have it delete the hidden rows. But using what I found here on SO (I am not sophisticated/skilled enough to write something like this myself yet), I wasn't able to find anything to help me do that as quickly as this did. So if that is something that would be possible, I would very much like to know how to do so.